# BS Authorize.net Problem (Payment in hanging if customers is not logged in)

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using BS Authorize.net plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/bs-authorize-net/) as a payment gateway in woocommerce which allows payment using credit card, Echeck and paypal. It works fine for logged-in user but for logged out user on checkout page, when clicking on Place order button after entering information, it hangs and do not proceeds the order (stays on same place). 
It gives following error on Chrome Developer console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()" https://site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. 
What could be the issue? Same issue occurred to a person and he asked for solution to their support and I saw no reply. 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/payment-in-hanging-if-customers-is-not-logged-in/

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Plugin support is considered off-topic here - we focus on custom code and working with Core functionality. You could try your host's support or search to see whether this plugin has any other support channels. Plugin devs often have their own sites where they provide support instead of through the .org support topics.

Comment: Hi WebElaine. Thanks for a quick response. I will try to find them :)